# What is side effect in C?

Tags: c, scope, side-effects, sequence-points

Wikipedia says that:

> *In computer science, an operation, function or expression is said to have a **side effect** if it modifies some state variable value(s) outside its local environment, that is to say has an observable effect besides returning a value (the main effect) to the invoker of the operation.*

But how can we access a variable outside its local environment, can anyone explain this situation, side effect, main effect and sequence point comprehensibly?

Comment: For example, a function modifies a global variable from within its code before it returns.

Comment: If you pass a variable by reference from a local scope to another scope the variable can be changed, unless the parameter is const type.

Comment: The code within a function resides within the scope of that function, and not in the global scope where the global variable is. If a function only returns a value and does not modify anything outside its scope, then it is called a pure function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A function is (should be) a black box, in which the return value, or the value of a variable passed by reference, should be the only thing that may change depending upon the input parameters.

Any other observable change that the function produces outside these cases, is a side-effect. The most well-known example may be the `printf()` function which, besides returning the number of written characters, changes the contents of the standard output, which means altering some memory buffer associated with a pipe, a file, or the screen, for instance, and which doesn't belong to the local environment of the function.

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing called "main effect" in the C language.

The formal definition of *side effect* in the C language (C17 5.1.2.3/2) is rather:

> Accessing a volatile object, modifying an object, modifying a file, or calling a function that does any
>   of those operations are all *side effects*, which are changes in the state of the execution environment.

Plainly, a side effect is:

- accessing a volatile variable, or
- writing to any variable,
- or writing to a file

(Where `stdout` is likely to regard as a file for the given system.)

This is relevant when determining if/how a compiler is allowed to optimize code (C17 5.1.2.3/4):

> In the abstract machine, all expressions are evaluated as specified by the semantics. An actual
>   implementation need not evaluate part of an expression if it can deduce that its value is not used and
>   that no needed side effects are produced (including any caused by calling a function or accessing a
>   volatile object).

But also when it comes to determine if an expression has well-defined behavior or not, which is where sequence points come in. Sequence points is however a big topic of its own, explained for example in several answers here: [Why are these constructs using pre and post-increment undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-pre-and-post-increment-undefined-behavior)

Answer (score 1):

A **State** is the attribute of a program which tells about the behavior of the program/function/variable.

for example, observe the state of "i" (variable):

```
int i = 0; // here state of i is only dependent on the value its holding. lets denote the time when i is having a value 0 as State A.
i++; // i = 1, that means its no longer 0 i.e. state changed to state B
i++ // i = 2 . State C
i--; // i = 1, state B
i += 0; // state B
```

***Side effects:*** 
In general, when someone talks about side-effects in a function (regardless of the language), they are talking about changes to the state of the program outside of changes to the function parameters and the object itself.

*The way I like to visualize side effect:*

```
----------------------
            \ <= side effect
           ----------------
```

A function with no side effects in C (where we disregard the possibility of a function being a member function) might look like this:

```
int stateOfP(int a, char *p)
{
  *p = 0;
   return a+1;
}
```

In this case, the program has modified a location in memory pointed to by p, but as p is a memory location pointed to in an argument, we don’t count that as a side effect.

A function without side effects is a good thing, for a few reasons.

*First*, the absence of side effects makes it easier for the compiler to optimize use of the function.

*Second*, side effects make it much more difficult to prove the correctness of a program.

*Finally*, when using multiple threads, particularly in a C program, side effects can have undetermined outcomes. For example, if two threads modify an ordinary global variable in a C program without some special locking mechanism, the program’s outcome is undefined.

What does it look like when a function has side effects? Something like this:

```
int a = 0;
void stateChange(int p)
{
  a++; // here the function is having side effects as 'a' is not its attribute
  return;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean when you say changes to the object itself ??

Comment: Here the state of the object means the state of the function itself.