# What is a side effect in C?

Tags: c, side-effects

In C99 clause 5.1.2.3 paragraph 2,

> Accessing a volatile object, modifying an object, modifying a file, or calling a function
> that does any of those operations are all *side effects*, which are changes in the state of
> the execution environment.

C standard defines *side effects* like above. But It seems C99 doesn't explain what exactly is accessing a volatile object, modifying an object, modifying a file(It's defined in the clause 3 what is the definition of access, modify, object. But accessing a volatile how? modifying what object? and modifying what of a file?). 
There are some examples in C99 as I search  with the word *side effects*. But I can't be sure whether each of examples is classified among accessing a volatile object, modifying an object and modifying a file.

I read [What is side effect in c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62148339/what-is-side-effect-in-c) and [Are side effects a good thing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/763835/are-side-effects-a-good-thing) but still am confused.
My question is that does the C standard explicitly describe a meaning of *side effects*? What they mean?

Comment: They intend to say that C is not a  *functional language*. In a (purely) functional language, there are no side effects.

Comment: @wildplasser Then does an object in `modifying an object` not stand for any identifier in C source code?

Comment: @opol an object need not have am identifier in C, just an lvalue expression that designates it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My question is that does the C standard explicitly describe a meaning of side effects?

The sentence in the C standard you quote (C 1999 5.1.2.3 2, and the same in C 2018) explicitly describes the meaning of *side effects*. These are further explained below.

### Modifying An Object

Modifying an object is understood to include the things that update the stored bytes that represent the object. I believe a complete list of them is:

- Simple assignment (`=`) and compound assignment (`*=`, `/=` `%=`, `+=`, `-=`, `<<=`, `>>=`, `&=`, `^=`, and `|=`).
- The increment and decrement operators (`++` and `--`), both prefix and postfix.
- Initialization of an object included in its definition.
- Library routines that are specified to change objects, such as `memcpy`.

### Accessing a Volatile Object

“Access” is defined in C 2018 3.1 as “⟨execution-time action⟩ to read or modify the value of an object”. If `x` is a `volatile int`, then using the value of `x` in an expression accesses it (when the expression is evaluated), because it reads the value of `x`. You can follow this more specifically in that 6.3.2.1 2 tells us that the use of `x` in an expression results in the value of `x` being taken:

> Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the unary `&` operator, the `++` operator, the `--` operator, or the left operand of the `.` operator or an assignment operator, an lvalue that does not have array type is converted to the value stored in the designated object (and is no longer an lvalue); this is called *lvalue conversion*.

So the `x` in the expression which is, by itself, just a designation of the object `x`, is converted to the value stored in `x`, which means that stored value is read from memory. That is an access of `x`.

Modifying a volatile object is the same as modifying any object, described above.

### Modifying a File

Files are modified by way of the routines defined in clause 7.21 (“Input/output `<stdio.h>`”).

Comment: I would add that function has side effects if it modifies anything except its own parameters (but of course not object referenced by the pointer parameters ) or its local objects.

Comment: I wouldn't count initialization into side effects

Answer (score 1):

Accessing a volatile object means *reading the value of a `volatile`-qualified object / an object through a volatile-qualified lvalue* - the standard says these need to be evaluated "*strictly* according to the rules of the abstract machine".

Modifying an object means *modifying **any object at all*** - modifying anything is considered a side effect. Example: an assignment operator has a side effect of modifying a variable it assigns the value to! In the following program. An assignment operator is used for its side effect!

Modifying a file means writing to the file, creating a file, deleting a file and so forth - anything that constitutes a change.

Examples of side effects from these categories:

```
void increment(int *p) {
    (*p) ++; // side effect - assign a new value to the 
             // object pointed to by p
}


int a = 5;
volatile int b = 6;
if (b == 6) { // side-effect of accessing a volatile variable
    a += b;   // calculate a + b, and as a side effect assign a new 
              // value to a
}

increment(&a);     // side effect - call a function that does
                   // one of the aforementioned operations
printf("%d\n", a); // side effect - change the state of an output stream

FILE *fp = fopen("foo", "w"); // side effect - create or truncate
fputc('!', fp); // side effect - modify file
fclose(fp);.    // side effect - close the file, flush 
remove("bar");. // side effect - remove file
```

---

There is a (way smaller) category of programming languages called pure functional languages, such as Haskell, whose computations are side-effect free. C is not one of such languages.

Comment: Not my vote, but assignments are not always used only for their side effects. `for (i = j = k = 0; …)` uses `j = k = 0` and `k = 0` for their values).

Comment: Also, none of the examples necessarily show side effects to a file. If the stream is fully buffered, the `printf` may change only the stream, which is constructed of data structures in memory. The changes do not necessarily reach the file immediately.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil What you want to say from `for (i = j = k = 0; ...)` uses `j = k = 0` and `k = 0`? . In this case, `=` is used for assignment to object, which causes a *side effect*(my thought).

Comment: I removed "only"

Comment: @opol: In `i = j = k = 0`, what is assigned to `j` is the value of `k = 0`. So `0` is not directly assigned to `j`; first `k = 0` produces `0`, and then that is assigned to `j`. Similarly, what is assigned to `i` is the value of `j = k = 0`. The value of an assignment is the value that will be stored in the left operand. This is more visible in an example such as `double x; int q; x = q = 3.5;`. The assignment converts the right value to the type of the left operand, so `3.5` is converted to `3`, and `3` will be stored in `q`. So `x` receives the value 3 (the value of `q = 3.5`), not 3.5.

Comment: @opol: Similarly, in `int x; unsigned char c; x = c = EOF;`, where `EOF` is −1, `x` would receive 255, not −1 (presuming 8-bit characters).

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I didn't know that. But then in `i = j = k = 0`, each of three `=` causes a side effect. First 0 to k, second k to j, third j to i. You said in first comment `but assignments are not always used only for their side effects`. Is this not called as a side effect?

Comment: @opol: They are used for their side effects but not **only** for their side effects. Whenever assignments appear in a chain or the value of an assignment is otherwise used in an expression (e.g., `int c; while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)…`), they are used **also** for their values.